# CCAction block "tweening"

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a `CCAction` similar to the `SKAction` in `SpriteKit` which get's called multiple times for the duration of the action (so you can create custom effects based on the time that has passed?)

I have found the `CCActionCallBlock`, but this is only called once and has no parameter for the "time passed."

E.g something like this (SpriteKit) in `Cocos2D`.

```
SKAction *customACtion = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:ANIMATION_TIME actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
    // Do something here
}];
```

The effect I am trying to achieve is [this](http://cl.ly/T5bf). Which in SpriteKit I can do like so:

```
#define ANIMATION_TIME 2

SKAction *customACtion = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:ANIMATION_TIME actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
    // Determine the percentage of the elapsed time
    float percentage = (elapsedTime / ANIMATION_TIME) * 100;
    // Put the result in a label
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", percentage];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cocos2d you can create multiple CCActions and put them in a container(CCSequence) in order to run one after another.

Here is an example of Composite actions..

```
id action1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(100,100)];
id action2 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2  position: ccp(80,80)];
id action3 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2  position: ccp(0,80)];
[sprite runAction: [CCSequence actions:action1, action2, action3, nil]];
```

The action1 will be executed first. When action1 finishes, then action2 will be executed. And when action2 finishes, only then action3 will be executed .

For More detail refer to this  [OFFICAL LINK](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_composition)

This can be dnoe by this..

```
 [self schedule: @selector(updateLabel:) interval:0.1] // Set interval,repeat whatever you want

 -(void) updateLabel: (ccTime) dt
  {
     if(dt>2000){
       [self unschedule:@selector(updateLabel)];
    }
     float percentage =percentage+ (dt/ (ANIMATION_TIME * 10));
      // Put the result in a label
     self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", percentage];

  }
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I am looking for, i've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: That looks useful. However. I would not be able to run the action in sequence that way from the looks of it. Or am I missing something.

Comment: It looks like "dt" never changes value it is always the interval value specified. I'll need to keep track of the correct value myself then. Anyway, I would love to have something as SKAction, but with some work this will work too.

Comment: you can do something like this...float percentage=percentage+(dt/(Animation_Time*10))